# Opera certificate from Trusted Authority on localhost

Tags: security, iis, certificate, opera

I'm using IIS Basic Authentication and my very last hurdle seems to be with Opera.  The certificate is not showing up as coming from 'A trusted Certificate Authority'.  I am doing this on localhost.  I've already copied the certificate from Personal to Trusted Root Certification.

Every other browser seems to work fine with Basic Auth and Opera seems to be stopping my progress.  The question is how do I have Opera see a trusted certificate on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Opera uses its own certificate/trust store and not the system one. You need to install your certificate in Opera's store to trust it. See how -> http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.60/en/security.html

Comment: Thanks!  That helped me narrow in some more.  I am currently running on Windows 7 to generate the self-signed certificate.  When I try importing the certificate in the available formats provided by windows it fails. Is there a quick work around for that?  Or a time consuming one?

Comment: What format does it want and what formats are available? You should also know that PFX and P12 formats are interchangable.